# Ubuntu server machine doesn't seem to be discoverable on network from another Linux machine

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, samba, file-sharing

I've installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 on the machine I use as my home server. I've installed Samba on it so I could use it as a local file server. However, although I configured Samba and rebooted, my server doesn't show up in **Networks** in Files on my computer (running Ubuntu 18.04).

I used to always be able to access it from there. I can still connect to the server via *Connect to server* but I'm just wondering why I'm no longer able to directly access it from **Networks**.

[image: Other Locations in file browser]

A machine called UBUNTU-SERVER should show up. It also doesn't appear on my raspberry pi, just in case that's helpful.

Comment: Folks, this question is not a duplicate. The "duplicate" answers the "How to create a samba share question". This question is "I created the samba share but I cannot see the server itself from my client". The original poster even stated "my server doesn't show up in Networks in Files". Even if you didn't create any shares you should still see the server. That's the way Samba works. And that is what I remedied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux-to-Linux host discovery without the use of any Windows-specific adjustments made to smb.conf you need to install the following package on your Ubuntu server:

```
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
```

Ubuntu enabled the ***multicast dns register*** option in the version of samba in 18.04 which will "announce" the server to the network but it will only work if avahi-daemon is installed on the server.

The avahi-daemon package should already be installed on all your Linux clients and its equivalent has been part of macOS for years.